# not able to comprehend gamma correction

Tags: image, image-processing, opengl, graphics

I am trying to comprehend gamma correction and I am not comprehend so many things.
I know there are so many question asked here but i am still confused so decided to post my confusion here.

Points of concepts that i have ( that does not mean i am able to interconnect them) after reading many blogs and watching series of youtube videos.

1. Our eye perceives illuminance in logarithmic way and sensor stores illuminance illuminance as it senses.
2. When image is stored with gamma encoding they are stored as `y = (x)^(1/2.2)` ( for gamma 2.2) and decoded as `y = x^2.2` ( for display gamma of 2.2)
3. Even though there is little illuminance, our eyes see it as brighter output ( thanks to logarithmic perception) [i hope i am not wrong here and this is the issue why we need gamma correction (i guess) ]

My confusion is:

1. If after encoding and decoding, the output is going to be linear like it was perceived by sensor, why do we need encoding and decoding in first place.
2. I found one statement in a blog that "when a digital image is saved, it is gamma encoded so that twice the value in file more closely corresponds to what we perceive as being twice as bright"
3. I see blogs and tutorials saying that " *goal is to distribute illuminance values according to how our eyes will perceive the light not how camera will perceive the light.*" I dont understand if my eye is feeded linear curve, that is how camera perceive light then how does this statement make sense.
4. Gamma encoded images store tones more efficiently. I dont understand how storing linear data into polynomial makes store tones more efficiently.
5. I think this is big statement that i am not able to understand "gamma encoding redistributes tonal levels closer to how our eyes perceive them".

Can anyone please help me connect dot here.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Gamma correction actually has very little to do with our eyes. It instead has to do with our *display* devices. Specifically, cathode-ray tube displays.

The guts of a CRT display works by firing an electron beam at a phosphor screen, causing that screen to glow for a short time. When scanning across the screen at a constant rate, the brightness of any one location is governed by the strength of the electron beam, and that strength is governed by the voltage going to the electron beam emitter.

A CRT-based television camera effectively does the reverse: it scans across an image, converting the brightness of each part of the image into a voltage. This voltage is modulated into a signal that is broadcast. A TV un-modulates the signal back into a voltage, which it applies to its own electron beam.

Here's the thing though. The relationship between the voltage and the eventual brightness caused by the electron beam is not a linear relationship. That is, twice the voltage did not result in twice the brightness. Brightness is proportional to Voltage raised to some power called γ (the Greek letter gamma). Exactly what γ is for a particular TV is variable, but they mostly hovered around 2.2.

For CRT-based video broadcasting, that's fine: the broadcaster has the same problem in reverse. When it converts the brightness to a signal, it functionally applies the inverse function, raising the brightness to the power of 1/γ.

When we wanted to start plugging computers into CRTs, we needed to apply the same concept. The signal being output has to be raised to the power 1/γ in order to display with the desired brightness. However, computer display hardware generally didn't do that, so their colors looked weird. Therefore, software solutions were found. Specifically, software would generate colors that were raised to the power of 1/γ. The graphics hardware would send the data as is, and the monitor would undo the gamma correction, thereby generating the intended colors.

Now, you may be wondering why this matters. You're not using a CRT and probably haven't for years if you're even old enough to have seen one. Well, there was a long period between when CRTs were relevant but LCDs and other display technologies existed. In order to be able to consume a signal intended for CRTs, they had to *assume* that the signal was gamma corrected.

And they have continued to do so, since even image formats kind of expect pixel data to be gamma corrected. Image editing software works in gamma corrected space and generates images that are gamma corrected. Thus you need to uncorrect the pixels when you sample them as textures (converting them into linear color values), do your linear math on them, then convert them back to gamma correct when writing to the display image.

Answer (score 1):

When saving an image from the sensor to file, the data is usually quantized (from maybe 10 or 12 bits to 8). This causes a small quantization error. To make it so that the error is least perceptible everywhere in the dynamic range (from black to white on the momitor), we want to increase the distance between dark intensities (where we see smaller differences in intensity) in exchange for decreasing the distance between bright intensities.

Of course it is even better to store the full 10 or 12-bit original data, but then you get files not compatible with many image display programs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for a response. I am not able to understand how gamma encoding redistributes tonal levels closer to how our eyes perceive them.

Comment: @PravinPoudel The sensitivity of your eyes to a light stimulus is non-linear. You are better able to distinguish between two very similar intensities near black than two equally different intensities near white. So by stretching out the darker intensities over a larger range, we are able to reduce the quantization error there. We now have a bigger quantization error near white, but we’re less sensitive to that.